# Check whether udf is registered in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I need to check whether a pyspark user defined function is registered before executing a sql command that uses it.  The udf in question is called `jaro_winkler_sim`.

I have some code that will do this using something like:

```
from pyspark.sql.utils import  AnalysisException
try:
    sql = "select jaro_winkler_sim('a', 'b')"
    spark.sql(sql)
    fn_exists = True
except AnalysisException as e:
    # handle error
    fn_exists = False
```

But I feel like there should be a more direct method.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `spark.catalog.listFunctions()` for this as follows:

```
def _check_jaro_registered(spark):
    for fn in spark.catalog.listFunctions():
        if fn.name == 'jaro_winkler_sim':
            return True
    return False
```

(Note `spark` is the `sparkSession` in the above)